# Get the most recent object for each category in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection that looks like this

```
{
  category: "Groceries",
  items: [...],
  price: 30.0,
  purchased: "04-10-2022 17:52:35"
},
{
  category: "Groceries",
  items: [...],
  price: 11.0,
  purchased: "04-10-2022 18:52:35"
},
{
  category: "Cleaners",
  items: [...],
  price: 10.0,
  purchased: "04-10-2022 17:52:35"
},
```

I want to take the most recent purchase for each `category` with one single query.

What the results should be are:

```
{
  category: "Groceries",
  items: [...],
  price: 11.0,
  purchased: "04-10-2022 18:52:35"
},
{
  category: "Cleaners",
  items: [...],
  price: 10.0,
  purchased: "04-10-2022 17:52:35"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to use sort to order all records purchased property
- Second group by the category and only push the first item.
- replace root to get the main record body.

```js
[
  // sort the dates to get the latest first
  {$sort: {purchased: -1}},
  // group to get the most recent purchased record per category
  {$group: {_id: '$category', record: {$first: '$$ROOT'}}},
  // replace root to get the main record body
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$record'}},
]
```

Comment: That works! But does that also mean that at some point the database will have all the objects that $match in-memory before selecting the first? Is this a concern?

Comment: yeah, that is right it will sort all records then pick the first, so I suggest you using index on category to make it fast